# Datalist pulling from one specific [mysql] database table with [php] code, but only first <option></option> is actually pulling data

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, bootstrap-modal, datalist

I am **not** looking to be spoon-fed the code to fix my problem. I'm a noob, like ridiculously. Maybe just a nudge in the right direction or criticism, whatever. I am creating this project for FUN. It is not for work, school or anything I get paid to do. Please be gentle if my question seems obvious to you.

-Webpage has multiple modals that open up when the user clicks on certain parts of the webpage.

-One of the bootstrap modals that pops-up shows an area for the "provider" information. This modal is working properly. The state field (state as in the state of Tennessee) is showing up in a filtered datalist pulled from a mysql database via php code! Woo hoo!!! 
----Pic #1 (provider state) ... I literally cannot post images because I don't have enough rep.

https://i.postimg.cc/NfD2xRKy/state-field.png

So far, so great!!

After the initial modal is closed, I open up another modal. The problem arises when that second/separate modal pops-up the state (Tennessee, etc) field does not have a filtered list. The first modal was for the provider's address and this second modal will be for the patient's address.

-I'm trying to pull the state (Tennessee, etc) data from the same database table (literally the same way the 1st modal is working). Unfortunately, the datalist filter isn't working on this second modal. I'm not getting any errors, the filter literally just never shows up when I click in the state field. 
----Pic #2 (patient state)

https://i.postimg.cc/mD4Tq6qT/state-field-two.png

I was able to do a work-around by *duplicating the table* in my database and just named the new table "17_state_Pay_To". The second modal literally works this way, but why do I need to duplicate the database table to get it to work properly?
----Pic #3 (database work-around)

https://i.postimg.cc/P5f36bK0/database-pic.png

Do I have to create / duplicate a table every time I want to pull from the same table on the same webpage? I'm going to be using the state one more time on this same webpage. It seems tedious, and the way I'm doing it is probably wrong.

*This is the code for the 1st (working) modal:*
`<datalist id="box2c2">
  <?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($resultEleven)){ ?>
     <option value="<?php echo $row['stateValue']; ?>"><?php echo $row['stateName']; ?></option>
  <?php } ?>
</datalist>`

*This is the code for the 2nd without the work-around.* Meaning, this modal isn't pulling from the duplicated table, this is pulling from the same table as the 1st (working) table. The only line that's different than above is the first line:
`<datalist id="box5c2">
  <?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($resultEleven)){ ?>
     <option value="<?php echo $row['stateValue']; ?>"><?php echo $row['stateName']; ?></option>
  <?php } ?>
</datalist>`

*For the work-around on the second modal, I only changed this line of code to pull from the duplicated table:*
`<?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($resultSeventeen)){ ?>`

**Describe expected and actual results:**
I would like to pull the State data from the same database table without needing to duplicate the table.

I don't know what else to put here ... I hope this is enough information.

Comment: `ctrl+k` is your friend, for code formatting.  Just FYI

Comment: It may be useful to see the source code that is generated by the one that does not work.  Does it even produce anything?  Perhaps you have no data to make it from, a problem with the query etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, this is what I would do:

Break the dependency on the DB, basically your trying to do too much with this one piece of code.

First create a generic function like this, to build your HTML.  This function needs to take the ID of the field, and an array of options that contain the value and the content of the option tag.

Something like this:

```
function createDataList($id, array $options){
   $html = ['<datalist id="'.$id.'">'];

   foreach($options as $value=>$content){ ?>
        $html[] = '<option value="'.$value.'">'.$content.'</option>';
   } 

   $html[] = '</datalist>';

   return implode("\n", $options);
}
```

Then when you need to use it you can pass an array like this:

```
 //the "value" should be unique so we can use that for the key,
 //then the other is what I like to call the "content"
 // [value=>content, value=>content]

 $options= ['foo'=>'This is foo', ...];
 echo createDataList('test', $options);
```

Expected output:

```
 <datalist id="test">
 <option value="foo">This is foo</option>
 ...
 </datalist>
```

The nice thing is you can get this array from anywhere. You can make it manually, you can make it from the DB.  For example:

```
$options= [];
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($resultEleven)){ 
     $options[$row['stateValue']] = $row['stateName'];
}

echo createDataList('box2c2', $options);
```

And for the second one:

```
$options= [];
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($resultSeventeen)){ 
     $options[$row['stateValue']] = $row['stateName'];
}

echo createDataList('box5c2', $options);
```

So you see this give you much more flexibility, and way less duplication.

Granted you have to loop over the data 2x instead of 1x, but unless your dealing in 10's of thousands of rows, I doubt you would notice it.  By the time you notice performance issues from that, your gonna be worrying about query times more.

Even if you have an existing array with a bunch of "junk" in it.

```
  $array = [['stateValue'=>'MI','stateName'=>'Michigan'], [...]];
```

You can use this to format it quickly.

```
  $data = array_column($array, 'stateValue', 'stateName');
  //result: ['MI' => 'Michigan', ...]
```

> **array_column (** array **$input** , mixed **$column_key** [, mixed **$index_key** = NULL ] **)**
>
> Returns the values from a single column of the input, identified by the column_key. Optionally, an index_key may be provided to index the values in the returned array by the values from the index_key column of the input array.
>
> https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php

One last tip, and this is a usability thing.  It may be worth wile to do the "content" this way:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($resultSeventeen)){ 
     $options[$row['stateValue']] = $row['stateValue'].' - '.$row['stateName'];
}

//result ['MI'=> 'MI - Michigan]
```

This way when the user types in `MI` or `CA` etc. it will effectively look up by the value, but still show them the full name.  This is something I have used with things like Months too.   `[1=>'1 - January']` etc...  But of course that part is totally up to you.  I just think it makes life a tad bit easier for the user.

**Summery**

Right now you have 2 pieces of "simular" code.  Wouldn't it be nice to have just one, then you know it works. It does it's job perfectly, and so you can focus your attentions on other parts of the application.  If it should happen to not work, you will be fairly confident that the fault lies elsewhere, so debugging will be easier etc...

Its just a good practice to make functions that do one thing, well.  Not procedural code that does many things poorly and is a mess to debug.  Then when you want to make more Datalists, even from unrelated data, you never have to touch that code again.  It just works.

Hope it helps you.

Comment: I literally had no idea there was a function called createDataList ... lol, I'm going to check out your array right now. Thank you **SO** much for your help. I upvoted your reply, but it said my rep was too low to be publicly acknowledged or something. Like the ticker didn't go to one, but you got the rep.

Comment: `I literally had no idea there was a function called createDataList` - there wasn't tell I invented it.  You can create one too....

Comment: Boom! ...and just like that, you're a genius. :) Thanks so much for your explanation. I have so much more to learn, but PHP is definitely the funnest language so far. Best answer as been clicked!

Comment: I have been doing PHP for about 11 years, learned it in 2008, got my first professional Job in 2010 ( after I got my associates).  I used to do Automotive Manufacturing.  But I messed around a lot with programing,  Such as Flash Actionscript,  Director Lingo (Flashes forgotten sibling, when it was still macromeda),  Modding for various Games etc...  I'm also a classically trained artist, The bird on my  profile I made by hand in Photoshop.   Anyway, Glad i could help.  Programing is wonderful way to express creativity.  My job is literally flipping 0's to 1's.